# Subir archivo con bootstrap input file en laravel 5

Tags: json, bootstrap, laravel-5

Estoy subiendo un archivo usando el plugin [bootstrap input file](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#ajax-uploads)
el cual logro subir con éxito en lo que presento dificulta el a la hora de devolver la ruta al plugin para poder ordenarlas o borrarlas en la documentación dispongo de 2 métodos que son

```
initialPreview: [
        '<img src='/images/desert.jpg' class='file-preview-image' alt='Desert' title='Desert'>',
    ],
```

y el otro es

```
initialPreviewConfig: [
    {
        caption: 'desert.jpg', 
        width: '120px', 
        url: 'http://localhost/avatar/delete', // server delete action 
        key: 100, 
        extra: {id: 100}
    }
]
```

pero indica que debo devolverlos en json lo cual realizo pero no pasa nada no actualiza el campo file este es mi controlador

```
public function Save(Request $request)
        {
                 if($request->ajax())
             {
               //obtenemos el campo file definido en el formulario
                $file = $request->file('input-25');

                //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
                $nombre = $file->getClientOriginalName();

                //indicamos que queremos guardar un nuevo archivo en el disco local
                \Storage::disk('local')->put($nombre,  \File::get($file));
               $public_path = public_path();
                 $url = $public_path.'/storage/'.$nombre;
                 $initialPreview= array(
                     '$url'
                );
                 return response()->json($initialPreview);

             }

        }
```

y este es el script del plugin

```
  $("#input-25").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: "{{ url('/subirpdf')}}",
        uploadExtraData: {_token:"{{csrf_token()}}"},
        language: "es",
        maxFileSize: 1000,
        required: true,
        allowedFileExtensions: ["pdf"],
        showRemove: true,
        initialCaption: "Subir Archivo en pdf con las caracteristicas del producto",
        msgFilerequired: true,
        showUploadedThumbs:false,
        initialPreviewAsData: true,

        deleteUrl:"{{ url('/eliminarpdf')}}",

    });
```

Comment: pues tu error radica en la respuesta que das en desde tu función `Save`, cuando haces `$url = $public_path.'/storage/'.$nombre;
                 $initialPreview= array(
                     '$url'
                );` le estas enviando la la path para que recupere la imagen y esta se visualice a los usuarios, lo que te falta enviar es una **ruta** de laravel la cual elimine la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos, tu `json` de respuesta estaría mal, razón por la cual no funciona tu botón borrar, si bien dices que tienes dos funciones :

**Primera:**

```
initialPreview: [
    '<img src='/images/desert.jpg' class='file-preview-image' alt='Desert' title='Desert'>',
],
```

en la cual debe de estar la `path`,`url` o `etiqueta` de la imagen que cargaste, lo cual ya debes de tener en `$url = $public_path.'/storage/'.$nombre;` que es tu código y suponiendo que ya la imagen ya se almaceno no deberia de haber problema hasta ahi.

**Segunda**

```
initialPreviewConfig: [
{
    caption: 'desert.jpg', 
    width: '120px', 
    url: 'http://localhost/avatar/delete', // server delete action 
    key: 100, 
    extra: {id: 100}
}]
```

donde `caption` es el nombre que se mostrara en la imagen cargada, `width` el ancho de la imagen, `url` es la url de eliminacion de imagen en el servidor en tu caso debe de existir una ruta en laravel (**Ej:** `Route::post('eliminarimagen/{id}','ImagenController@eliminar');`) donde en la funcion `eliminar` debe de estar los pasos correspondientes para eliminar la imagen, seguimos con `key` que puede ser el id de tu imagen en tu base de datos, y `extra` donde deben de estar todos los datos extra que necesites, en laravel muchas veces se envia el `_token`.

Explicado todo eso, publico un ejemplo basico:

```
$temporal->save();
$key=$temporal->id;
$url = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::root().'/eliminarimagen/'.$temporal->id;//ruta total de eliminacion
$res1[0] =\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::root().$temporal->image;//nombre de la imagen
$res2[0] = ['caption' => $temporal->image, 'width' => '120px', 'url' => $url, 'key' => $key,'extra'=>['_token'=>$token]];
return json_encode([
    'initialPreview' => $res1,
    'initialPreviewConfig' => $res2,
    'append' => true
]);
```

Donde `$temporal` es el objeto que almaceno la imagen en la base de datos(No se si en tu caso fuera necesario), y `$temporal->image` contiene la path de la imagen.

Espero te sirva de algo.