# Problema redireccionar laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una página en la que almaceno imágenes en una carpeta del proyecto y el nombre del archivo de imagen lo almaceno en la BBDD. Hasta ahí todo correcto, puedo guardar y eliminar las imágenes de la carpeta y a la vez elimino los datos almacenados en la BBDD. Mi problema viene a la hora de volver a la página en donde selecciono la/s imagen/es una vez que he eliminado alguna de ellas. Obtengo el siguiente error y no se como solucionarlo:

```
{
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
"file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\Opencart\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
"line": 179,
```

}
En la consola de Chrome me figura error 404 No encontrado.
[image: Error 404 No encontrado]

El controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //obtenemos el campo file y el id definido en el formulario
    $files           = $request->file('imagenes');
    $id              = $request->input('id');
    $destinationPath = public_path() . '\images\productos';

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
        $nombre         = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       //Movemos el archivo a la carpeta images
        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $nombre);
      // Redimensionar imagen
        $imagesizer          = new imgSizer();
        $imagesizer->type    = "width";
        $imagesizer->max     = 160;
        $imagesizer->quality = 8;
        $imagesizer->square  = true;
        $imagesizer->prefix  = "miniatura_";
        $imagesizer->folder  = "_min";
        $imagesizer->image   = "/images/productos/" . $nombre;
        $imagesizer->resize();
        $infoImagenesSubidas = array("height" => "160px");
        $imagenesSubidas     = "<img src='/images/productos/_min/miniatura_" . $nombre . "'> height='160px' class='file-preview-image'>";

        //Guardamos en la BBDD ruta y el id del producto
        Image::create([
            'image_path' => $nombre,
            'product_id' => $id,
        ]);
    }

    $arr = array("file_id" => 0, "overwriteInitial" => true, "InitialPreviewConfig" => $infoImagenesSubidas, "InitialPreview" => $imagenesSubidas);
    echo json_encode($arr);

}
 public function destroy($id)
{
    $image = Image::find($id); 

    $image->delete();

    if (file_exists(public_path('images/productos/' . $image->image_path))) {
        unlink(public_path('images/productos/' . $image->image_path));
        unlink(public_path('images/productos/_min/miniatura_' . $image->image_path));
    }

    return redirect()->to('/admin/products/image/store');
}
```

Cuando refresco la página el proceso de eliminación concluye correctamente; elimina la imagen y vuelvo a la página. El error sucede cuando pulso el botón eliminar.
[image: Eliminar imagen]

Archivo de rutas:

```
    Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index'); // pagina web
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin');
    Route::get('/admin/products/', 'ProductController@allProducts')->name('admin.products'); // Muestra todos los productos
    Route::get('/admin/active', 'ProductController@index')->name('admin.products.active'); // Muestra los productos activos
    Route::get('/admin/inactive', 'ProductController@inactiveProducts')->name('admin.products.inactive'); // Muestra los productos sin stock
    Route::get('/admin/show/{id}', 'ProductController@show')->name('products.show'); //Muestra los datos del producto seleccionado para poder ediatrlo
    Route::get('/products/{id}/subcategories', 'SubcategoryController@GetSubcategory'); //combos dependientes show-products.balde.php
    Route::post('/admin/update/{id}', 'ProductController@update')->name('products.update'); // Actualiza los datos del producto
    Route::get('/admin/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('products.create'); //Muestra el formulario para crear un nuevo producto
    Route::post('/admin/store', 'ProductController@store')->name('products.store'); // Guardar un nuevo registro
    Route::post('/admin/delete/{id}', 'ProductController@destroy')->name('products.destroy'); // eliminar registro
    Route::get('/admin/recover', 'ProductController@showProductsDelete')->name('admin.products.recover'); //Muestra la tabla con los elementos de eliminación suave
    Route::get('/admin/restore/{id}', 'ProductController@restoreProductsDelete')->name('admin.products.restore'); // Recupera un registro en concreto por su id

    Route::get('/admin/image/{id}', 'ImageController@show')->name('admin.products.image'); //Muestra el formulario para subir imágenes
    Route::post('/admin/image/store', 'ImageController@store')->name('admin.products.store'); //Guarda imágenes
    Route::delete('/admin/products/image/destroy/{id}', 'ImageController@destroy')->name('admin.products.image.destroy'); 
    //Elimina imágenes

});
```

Vista:

```
@extends('admin.layout')

@section('style')
        <!-- CSS Fileinput-->
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@endsection

@section('content-header')
<section class="content-header">
      <h1>
       {{$title}}

      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>

        <li class="active">Imágenes</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
@endsection


@section('content')
        @if(Session::has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Correcto!</h4>
               {{Session::get('message')}} 
              </div>
              @endif
        <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Seleccionar imágenes</h3>

          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Collapse">
              <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Remove">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
         <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="">
             {{csrf_field()}}

                    <input type="file" name="imagenes[]" id="images" multiple class="file-loading">

                     </form> 
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
        <div class="box-footer">
          Footer
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer-->
      </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts-fileinput')

<script>
$('#images').fileinput({
    uploadUrl:"{{route('admin.products.store')}}",
    language:"es",
    theme:"fa",
    uploadAsync:false,
    minFileCount:1,
    maxFileCount:6,
    allowedFileExtensions:["jpg","png"],
    showRemove:false,

    uploadExtraData:{'_token': "{{csrf_token()}}",'id':"{{$product->id}}"},
    deleteExtraData:{'_token': "{{csrf_token()}}",'_method':'delete'},

    initialPreview: 
    [
        @foreach ($image as $element)
        @php
    $imagesizer= new imgSizer();
    $imagesizer->type= "width";
    $imagesizer->max = 200;
    $imagesizer->quality=8;
    $imagesizer->square=true;
    $imagesizer->prefix="miniatura_";
    $imagesizer->folder="_min";
    $imagesizer->image="/images/productos/".$element->image_path;
    $imagesizer->resize();
    @endphp
            '<img src="{{"/images/productos/_min/miniatura_$element->image_path"}}" height="160px" class="file-preview-image">',
                     @endforeach 
    ],

    initialPreviewConfig:[

    @foreach ($image as $element)
    { caption:"{{$element->image_path}}", height:"120px",url:"{{ url('admin/products/image/destroy',$element->id) }}",key:"{{$element->id}}"},

    @endforeach


    ]
})
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Creo que necesitaremos el código de la vista también, para entender qué botón es presionado.

Comment: Utilizo el plugin Bootstrap FileInput, el botón que se presiona es el que presenta el plugin, es decir, no tengo un botón programado al efecto.

Comment: Hace un par de meses atras respondi a un error similar a este que de igual forma trabaja con el mismo puglin, en el cual explique con un ejemplo completo el manejo de Bootstrap InputFile, te dejo el link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114123/subir-archivo-con-bootstrap-input-file-en-laravel-5/114143#114143 Espero te sirva.

Comment: La captura de pantalla de la consola de Chrome que pusiste dice que estás haciendo la petición a `http://opencart.dev.com/...`. Pregunto: ¿el dominio es **".dev.com"**? me resulta raro y seguramente por eso el error es un **404 Not Found**.

Comment: Si, es dev.com tengo creado un virtual host con Laragon

Comment: Muchas gracias Shassain, voy a verlo y os cuento como ha ido.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, en el momento que pueda probaré alguna de las rutas que me indicas.

Comment: @belkin220, y si no lo logras informas, para ver otras formas de solucion.

Comment: Después de analizar el error descrito en ambas preguntas, no veo como podría solucionar la otra respuesta al problema enunciado aquí, si el error es un 404. Además podrías haber agregado esta información en un comentario.

Answer (score 1):

### Estas tratando de redirigir a una ruta que es mediante post y a la cual no le estas pasando ningun dato por post

```
return redirect()->to('/admin/products/image/store'); //redirect en la funcion destroy
Route::post('/admin/image/store', 'ImageController@store')->name('admin.products.store'); //Guarda imágenes
```

### Lo mas conveniente es mandarlo a esta ruta que ya tienes declarada y es get

```
return redirect()->to('/admin/products/'); //redirect en tu funcion destroy
Route::get('/admin/products/', 'ProductController@allProducts')->name('admin.products'); // Muestra todos los productos
```

Comment: Hola pboss, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Ya lo intenté con esa ruta también, además de las que me indicó shaz. El resultado fue SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. Como he indicado en el comentario anterior lo solucioné retornando un JSON vacío: return '{}' y ahora funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás redireccionando a una ruta que no está definida al momento de borrar la imagen:

```
return redirect()->to('/admin/products/image/store');
```

Debería ser una ruta GET válida, por ejemplo:

```
return redirect()->to('/admin/show/' . $product->id);
```

O mejor aún, utilizar un nombre de ruta:

```
return redirect()>route('products.show', ['id' => $product->id]);
```

Comment: Algo estás haciendo mal, revisa la documentación.

Comment: Después de muchas pruebas y centrándome en las indicaciones de Shaz no logré solucionar el problema con el redireccionamiento. Por último el error que estuve obteniendo era SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. Indagando encontré la solución retornando un JSON vacío: return '{}'. Ahora todo funciona sin problemas, pero no entiendo que problema hay con hacer una redirección o mostrar una vista, que no ha funcionado de ninguna manera. Gracias a todos